# Django and AWS S3: Storing and securing private files

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Django app that will invoke an API call (a Python function) to create a folder with a private S3 bucket. To invoke the function, a user will have to be logged in first.

The S3 bucket will look like this:

```
s3://somebucket/user1
s3://somebucket/user2
and so on
```

API call: `https://somedomain.com/createfolder/user1`

I don't want to allow user2 to call the API by substituting the `user1` string with his username.

Assuming I can secure this API call, my Python function will then just go ahead and create a folder with the username given to it.

user1 will also have the ability to download only his/her files.

users can log in to my app via OAuth2 or username/password.

The questions:
a. How do I secure my API so that user2 cannot commit actions on user1?
b. Similarly, how do I create pre-signed URLs pointing to user1's file (a specific file, which could be a zipped form of a folder?

My research: I have heard of JWT and pre-signed URLs, but I'm having difficulties in understanding how to practically implement them in Django.

Comment: What is your "API" - where does it live? Is it AWS API Gateway with your python function in AWS Lambda or does it live outside? Where?